# session methods aren't working in python async request

Tags: python, asynchronous, session, async-await, python-asyncio

I am trying to make an async request using the session object.

What I have done so far is:

1. Setting a clientSession obj:

   `async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:`
2. Pass the session to method:

   `full_process(user, email, session)`
3. Call methods for api calls:

```
async def full_process(user, email, session):
   res1 = await get_data(user, session)
   res2 = await get_image(user, session)
```

4. Perform api calls:

```
async def get_data(user, session):
   r = await session.get('SOME_URL')
   return r
```

The problem here is that, in step 4, the line for the await process doesn't even execute, or that's what I think.
I simply added two print functions to verify the problem:

```
async def get_data(user, session):
   print('before call')
   r = await session.get('SOME_URL')
   print('RESULT: ', r)
   return r
```

but the second print is never executed

What am I doing wrong? Sorry if it is something obvious I am new to python
Im using python 3.6.7

Here's the full code:

```
async def get_data(user, session):
   print('EXEC DATA')
   r1 = await session.get('SOME_URL')
   print('R1: ' + str(r1))
   return r1

async def get_image(user, session):
   print('EXEC IMAGE')
   r2 = await session.get('SOME_URL')
   print('R2: ' + str(r2))
   return r2

async def full_process(user, email, session):
   print('FULL PROCESS STARTED')
   res1 = await get_data(user, session)
   print('FIRST RES: ' + str(res1))
   if res1 and 'email' in res1:
      res2 = await get_image(user, session)
      print('SEC RES: ' + str(res2))

async def main_block():
   tasks = []
   some_data = [{some_obj}, {some_obj}, {some_obj}]
   async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
      for line in some_data:
         tasks.append(full_process(user, email, session))
   await asyncio.gather(*tasks, return_exceptions=True)

print('Starting...')
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(main_block())
print('End...')
```

Executing this code gives me this result (simulating 3 items in some_data array):

```
Starting...
FULL PROCESS STARTED
EXEC DATA
FULL PROCESS STARTED
EXEC DATA
FULL PROCESS STARTED
EXEC DATA
End...
```

I just want to point out that the full script works. There are no errors, it starts and finish without issues, but obviously the api calls aren't made.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't think this is really your program.  First of all, it contains undefined variables.  Second, the failure to print "R1" (and also the failure to print "FIRST RES") indicates that the line await get_data did not finish execution.  But the successful printing of "EXEC IMAGE" indicates that full_process somehow managed to get as far as await get_image().  That makes no sense.  You stand a much better chance of getting help if you can present a program that others can run.

Comment: Your conclusion that the failure to print RESULT indicates that the await expression didn't execute does not follow.  Like any other function call, in principle session.get() can raise an exception.  Also an await expression does not return immediately - that's kind of the point of it - so the next line of code after the await may take a while to execute.  Exception handling in asyncio programs is not always straightforward; in some cases exception can be swallowed silently.  Your program doesn't have any exception handling, and for a program that does I/O you always need some.

Comment: @PaulCornelius sorry, I have edited the question because the result is wrong. Calling the first function get_data is the only one that executes the first print. I understand that the second print means that something happened with await get_data but I have also put that code inside a try except block and it didn't fail.

Comment: @PaulCornelius the second call to get_image also was edited as it depends of the first response, and since the first api call always results in None, then the get_image process is never executed.

Comment: The docs for asyncio.gather say: "If return_exceptions is True, exceptions are treated the same as successful results, and aggregated in the result list."  You never look at the result list from gather, so if an exception occurs you would never know it.  That's the only possible explanation I can see here.  The program must print FIRST RES or raise an exception - it cannot simply vanish into thin air.

Comment: You say that you have put that code inside a try block, but what code?  The failing line appears to be `await session.get` in `get_data`.  While you're at it, I would add a finally block to that where I would print something with 100% certainty.  I don't know the internals of aiohttp, but be aware that if an asyncio,CancelledError is raised it can be tricky - it's a subclass of BaseException, not Exception.  That can slip through if you don't check for it explicitly.

Comment: Thanks anyway @PaulCornelius, I found the answer it was totally related to print errors, kinda strange because usually these errors cause an exception even when not handled but nothing happened and program ended without any exceptions. After removing these bad prints, everything worked (trying to print obj without parsing to str)